# NUnit Run OneTimeSetUps after OneTimeTearDowns of other tests

Tags: nunit

How do I organize tests so that their OneTimeSetUps are run after OneTimeTearDowns of others is done? The tests need conflicting setups, but all OneTimeSetUps are run first thing, so this doesn't work.

I made a small setup. Foo and Bar, with their respective OneTimes, are in different namespaces in different classes each tagged with [TestFixture]. This is the order things are run:

```
FooOneTimeSetUp
BarOneTimeSetUp
Foo
FooOneTimeTearDown
Bar
BarOneTimeTearDown
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out what I want is default behavior. However, the project I was working on had set `[assembly: Parallelizable(ParallelScope.Children)]`, which causes the unwanted behavior in my question, even though `[assembly: LevelOfParallelism(1)]` was also set and enforced similarly by the runners.

This is explained in the docs here:
https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/technical-notes/usage/Framework-Parallel-Test-Execution.html